# Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic no constant, then $\mbox{Re}f+\mbox{Im}f$ has no minimum in $U$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $U\in\mathbb{C}$ be an open and connected set and let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic. Suppose that $f$ is not constant. Show that $\mbox{Re}f+\mbox{Im}f$ has no minimum in $U$.

**Remark:** I think I should use the Maximum Modulus Principle but I don't see how it can be used.

Comment: $\operatorname{Re}f$ and $\operatorname{Im}f$ are harmonic functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Prove by contradiction. First prove $\mbox{Re}f+\mbox{Im}f$ is harmonic by showing it satisfies Laplacian equation. Then prove bounded harmonic function $u$ must be constant by the fact that $e^{-u-iv}$ ($v$ is harmonic conjugate of $u$) is bounded entire.

Comment: I do not see necessary to use the fact that $f$ is harmonic. I think I proved this result, my proof is: Consider $g(z)=e^{(i-1)f(z)}$, note that $g$ is holomorphic in $U$ because $f$ is holomorphic in $U$, also note that $\left|g(z)\right|=e^{-(\mbox{Re}f+\mbox{Im}f)}$. If $\mbox{Re}f+\mbox{Im}f$ has minimum then $\left|g(z)\right|$ has maximum in $U$. Therefore, by Maximum Modulus Principle we have that $g$ is constant, then $(i-1)f(z)$ is constant, so $f$ is constant, which it is a contradiction.